# How to get x from $\tan(x)$ knowing the sign of $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have access to tan(x) and I want to deduce x from it. However if use the inverse of tan(x) I got x[$\pi$] and not directly x. For example:

$$tan^{-1}(tan(\pi)) = 0 $$

Knowing the sign of cos(x) and sin(x) is there a way I can correct this to have the value of x in the interval $ [0,2\pi)$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Hint: What are the signs of $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ for $x$ in each of the $4$ quadrants?

Comment: @JohnOmielan well for x between 0 and $\pi/2$ cos and sign are postive for x between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$ the cos is negative, for x between $\pi and 3\pi/2$ the cos and sin are negative and for x between $3\pi/2 and 2\pi$ only the sin is negative. Hmm does it work if i just add $\pi$ to the x I got from $tan^{-1}$ whenever the sin is negative ?

Comment: It is not possible to give *all* the angles in $[0,2\pi]$.  Which do you want:  $[0,2\pi)$ or $(0,2\pi]$?

Comment: My mistake, I want [0, 2$\pi$)

Comment: @Rhecsu With $\sin(x)$ being negative, consider the $2$ possibilities for the sign of $\cos(x)$. Since the range of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is usually $\left(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, note adding $\pi$ will not work properly if $\cos(x)$ is positive. Consider what you would need to add to the result instead in that case.

Comment: If you're doing something programming related, look up `atan2` - it does exactly the thing  you're after (well, maybe different exact output range - but always a full turn) and every programming language I've used has an implementation of it.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Yes it's related with programming with python, thank you I will look at that

Comment: @JohnOmielan I think I understand know, if cos(x) is positive and sin(x) negative I need to add 2$\pi$

Comment: @Rhecsu Great! Yes, I believe you got it now, with this & other details also being in the accepted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3655820/602049).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triple $(\tan x, \sin x, \cos x)$ is periodic with minimal period $2\pi$, so the best you can do with the information you have is to find the equivalence class of such $x$s modulo $2\pi$.

$$  \hat{x} = \begin{cases}
\arctan \tan x ,& \cos x > 0 \text{ and } \sin x \geq 0,  \\
\pi/2 ,& \cos x = 0 \text{ and } \sin x = 1,  \\
\pi + \arctan \tan x ,& \cos x < 0,  \\
3\pi/2 ,& \cos x = 0 \text{ and } \sin x = -1, \\
2 \pi + \arctan \tan x ,& \cos x > 0 \text{ and } \sin x < 0
\end{cases}  $$
The first case handles the quadrantal angle zero and the first quadrant.  The second case handles the quadrantal angle $\pi/2$.  The third case handles the second and third quadrants as well as the quadrantal angle $\pi$ between them.  The fourth case handles the quadrantal angle $3\pi/2$.  The fifth cases handles the fourth quadrant.

Then $\hat{x} \in [0,2\pi)$ and $x = \hat{x} + 2\pi k$, for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

For each real $ x\le 0$
$$\frac{-\pi}{2}<tan^{-1}(x)\le 0$$

and for $ x\ge 0,$

$$0\le tan^{-1}(x)<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

For example, assume $$\tan(x)=a$$
$$\cos(x)\le 0$$
$$\sin(x)\ge 0$$

then

$$x = tan^{-1}(a)+\pi$$